# Worst case runtime in Big-Theta notation

Tags: algorithm

What is the worst case run time in Big-Theta notation for the code below? The code calculates the average of homework scores from a list of homework scores after dropping the lowest score.

```
m := 1
for i := 2 to n
    if h_i < h_m then m := i
total := 0
for j := 1 to n
    if j != m then total := total + h_j
return total/(n − 1)
```

At worst case, this would mean the lowest score is situated in the last position. This implies at the first loop, it would run n-1 iterations. Both the upper-bound and lower-bound of the first loop is O(n) and Ω(n) respectively. I believe this would mean it has a runtime of Θ(n)

The second loop is pretty much the same thing, except it's n iterations.

I wonder for the overall runtime of the whole program, do we use max(Θ(n),Θ(n)) = Θ(n) like we do with big-O notations i.e. max (O(n),(O(1)) = O(n)?

I asked this question because supposedly I modified above code to run on only ONE loop :-

```
m := 1 ; total = h_1
for i := 2 to n
    if h_i < h_m then m := i
    total = total + h_i
total = total - h_m
return total/(n − 1)
```

This code also runs n-1 iterations => Θ(n). Now this seems weird to me because obviously the first code has a longer runtime than the second code since it has two loops. Which is why I asked is it correct to use max (Θ(f(n)) , Θ(g(n)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're falling into a common mistake of thinking that big-O/θ notation tells you the run time.  It doesn't, it tells you how the run time will (asymptotically) scale as a function of `n`.  If algorithm 1 grows linearly in `n`, and algorithm 2 takes twice as long to run as algorithm 1, algorithm 2 still has linear growth as well.  That's why we ignore any scaling constants for big-O/θ.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same as with big-O notation, constant factors are dropped. So the whole runtime is `Θ(2n) = Θ(n)`.

Also, having two loops doesn't mean a longer runtime, because the loops can be shorter or do less per iteration. Your second program does more per iteration so total runtime would be about the same.

Answer (score 0):

You don't return before the finish of the iteration that means you always go through the full list